# AR not supported xampp

Tags: javascript, xampp, localhost

i'm trying to use website on javascript to show 3D model of mountains. The problem is that the site created on xampp shows "AR not supported". Is it xampp issue?

Answer (score 0):

Showing 3D models can be done with XAMPP and Apache.
Your error may be caused by a lot of things so it's hard to give a one solution.

**Possible solution/workaround:**

1. Check if you have the latest versions of software
2. Try with some other model and check if any 3D models work
3. Another solution could be to use AMPPS instead of XAMPP.